# Google App Engine + Jinja2: Using self.redirect() with params

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

Let's say I have a `Book ndb.Model class.`

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
```

*Book* entities are created by this handler:

```
     def get(self):
         self.render('new-book.html')

     def post(self):
          title = self.request.get('title')

         if title:
            b = Book(title = title)
            b.put()
            self.redirect('/book/%s' % str(b.key.id()))
```

When a Book entity is created, we are redirected to the `/book/[book id]`. On this page, I would like to include a message which says "*Good job! You've created [book title].*" How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using django?

Comment: Oops, I am using Jinja2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not include your message in the url and then place it where you want it using javascript?

```
self.redirect('/book/%s?message=%s' % (str(b.key.id()), "Good job! You've created " + title)
```

for the js do something like this...

```
alert(document.location.substring(document.location.indexOf("?message=")+9, document.location.length));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. This seems like a simple, effective solution (even without the Javascript part; I can use `self.request.get('message')`). One issue we have here is that we are redirected to the path, for example, `/book/[book id]?message=message`, and if this link is shared, this same message will appear on other visitors. We don't want that. Any idea how to get pass this?

Comment: Are you storing the user who created the book?  If so you could say something like if(BookCreator == CurrentUser):  Jinja2message = self.request.get('message')

Answer (score 0):

I would just simply do it like

`main.py` or whatever else you use for your app something like:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([

    ('/book/([^/]+)?', server.BookHandler)

], debug=True)
```

`Handlers` something like:

```
def get(self):
    self.render('new-book.html')

def post(self):
    title = self.request.get('title')

    if title:
        b = Book(title = title)
        b.put()
        self.redirect('/book/%s/' % str(b.key.id()), abort=True)

#...more stuff

#on handler for book
def get(self, message):
    #use message

    self.response.out.write(message)
```